# While clicking on the contect asist sample codes are not showing on the eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, eclipse-plugin, popup

When I'm using ctrl+space for content assist there is no sample code that is popping in my system. It only shows the content assist.
Sample code like this image is not showing for me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you add the library needed like for example if you're using TestNG you should add it's library the same thing applies for Junit  you can do it by
going to configure build path --->add library

(also don't forget the selenium you should add its jar)

Comment: Yes I've added the jars of selenium and TestNG as well however, the code suggestions are not showing for the org.openqa.selenium part, but it's showing for the java operations.